# Is NMR possible using nitrogen as the nucleus?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

Is NMR spectroscopy performed using nitrogen nuclei? If yes, then where?

Comment: 15N is NMR active (spin 1/2) and is commonly used in protein NMR (amongst other uses). Did you see that there is a Wikipedia page on it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen-15_nuclear_magnetic_resonance_spectroscopy

Comment: and before you ask  also of many other nuclei, $\ce{^2H, ^{10}B,^{11}B, ^{17}O,^{19}F,^{27}Al,^{29}Si,^{31}P,^{129}Xe}$ among others :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course yes -- because of the spin $\ce{^{15}N}$ and the much lesser used $\ce{^{14}N}$ nuclei posses:

[image]

The image is from [here](http://chem.ch.huji.ac.il/nmr/techniques/1d/row2/n.html), the site provides some useful additional  overview to the source mentioned by @orthocresol.

---

P.S. If there were no NMR active nitrogen nuclei, [3D NMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-resonance_nuclear_magnetic_resonance_spectroscopy) would not this widespread in protein research:

[image]

([source](http://www.protein-nmr.org.uk/solution-nmr/assignment-theory/visualising-3d-spectra/))

Comment: Thanx man! Actually I just started my spectroscopic studies and hence was not aware of the fact.